# Is it possible to keep the Xcode command line tools installed on my system after macOS updates?

Tags: macos, xcode, software-update

I don't have Xcode on my computer, but until about a year ago I'd always managed to install the command line tools simply by running

```
xcode-select --install
```

Since then this command fails with [Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907576/xcode-is-not-currently-available-from-the-software-update-server), and I haven't been able to fix it.

That is particularly painful because after every os update (I'm currently on 11.1 beta) the installed tools disappear and I have to install them again — and as they can't be installed through CLI, I have to manually download them from Apple's developer portal.

I've given up on making the CLI work, but is it possible to keep the tools installed after a system update?

Comment: I managed to solve a half of this issue: I dropped the beta and now the cl tools can be installed through `xcode-select --install` again. I still have to reinstall them after every update, but at least it's not as painful.